# Inserting '2011-12-20, 3:18PM EST' into MySQL Timestamp Column

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to insert timestamps in the form of `2011-12-20,  3:18PM EST` into a TIMESTAMP column in a MySQL table.

**Problem:** Inserting the string `2011-12-20,  3:18PM EST` directly into the table gets me `2011-12-20 03:18:00` which is in AM! (Took me very long to discover this!!)

Now when I tried the following, I get a PHP error...

```
$time = '2011-12-20,  3:18PM EST';

echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
```

I also tried inserting the output of `strtotime('2011-12-20,  3:18PM EST')` into the MySQL table, which just gets me `000-00-00 00:00:00`.

**Question:** Which is the correct way to insert the string like `2011-12-20,  3:18PM EST` into the TIMESTAMP column of the table? I want `2011-12-20 15:18:00` to end up in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the 'EST' part:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2011-12-20, 3:18PM'));
```

You could do that with [substr](http://php.net/substr)() or [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace)()